# How do I allow allow a user to add values to a picklist fields for lead objects

Tags: fields, configuration, setup-object

How do I allow allow a user to add values to a picklist fields for lead objects.

Show I create a permission set?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want them to be able to change other setup items (Not recommended) I suggest you implement a process where they request the addition and an admin approves and implements it.

Generally, you do not want users to add values to a pick list randomly. If you feel it is necessary consider changing the field to a text field.

Additionally, as long as it is not a restricted picklist you can enter anything into the field using visual force or data loader.

Comment: I cannot create a new field for this. Can I use permission set to allow user to update values in lead source field

Comment: Sure (I hope you read my answer though) because they can change anything is setup)